# Why aren't my conditional statements working with regular expressions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-statements

I've just started learning about regular expressions. I wrote a basic program to test myself, but the conditional statements never fire. Here's my code:

```
console.log("running program...")

if("a" == /[a-zA-Z]/){           //if "a" is a letter character (should be true)
    console.log("it worked");
};
```

What part of my syntax is wrong?

EDIT: Thanks to quantas, hanky and felix for the help and explanation!

Comment: You are comparing whether the string `"a"` **is** the regular expression `/[a-zA-Z]/`, which of course it is not. [Learn more about regular expressions in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), especially read the section *Working with Regular Expressions*.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to test for a match is using the [`test()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.3) function:

```
console.log('running program...');
if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test('a')) console.log('it worked');
```

This returns a boolean, depending on whether the string given matches the regular expression or not. To learn more about using regular expressions, see [the MDN article on regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

The `==` operator just checks for whether they are the same value in a specific form. Your original code just tested whether the string `"a"` is a reference to the same object as the RegExp object `/[a-zA-Z]/`, and as they aren't the same object, it will return `false`. When you did this:

```
"a" == /[a-zA-Z]/
```

In this instance, it will convert the `RegExp` object to a string, which then results in a check on whether `"a"` is the same as `"/[a-zA-Z]/"`, which is of course not true.

Answer (score 2):

You have to [**test**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) a `regex`, and not just compare it with a `string`.

```
 var s = "a";
 var pattern = /[a-zA-Z]/;
 var result = pattern.test(s);  // either true or false

 //for your condition it is
 if(pattern.test(s))
 {
  console.log("it worked");
 }
```